# C++ template programming: why T[] and R(A1, A2, A3) are viewed as types?

Tags: c++11

For example:

```
std::unique_ptr<Box[]> Boxes(new Box[5]);
std::function<int(doube, double)> funcobj;
```

But for any variable x, decltype(x) cannot be T[] or call signature R(A1,...)

Comment: They're types, you just can't declare instances of them.  Kind of like abstract class types.

Comment: @Chris: You can declare using a function type just fine, doing so forward-declares a function (not a variable).

Comment: @BenVoigt: thats a forward declaration, not declaring an instance.  You can't declare a variable of a function type.  You can declare a function which is an instance of a kind, but its not something you can assign to or copy.

Comment: @ChrisDodd; The same is true of reference types.  They are types, they can be used to declare things, but they are not *object types* so what they declare are not *objects*.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your helpful discussion.

Now I understand that both are truly types. You can use them in typedef declaration. But they are special you cannot use them as normal types. Here is an example to use these types.

```
typedef int function_type(int, int);
typedef char char_array[];

// char_array arr; // Not allowed
char_array str = "hello";
function_type add;  // like function declaration;

// function add defined here.
int add(int a, int b) {
   return a+b;
};
```